# Jquery condition with a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

hi i have any problem with a condition, when i uncheck the checkbox, it don't uncheck. I've to make block a display, but javascript don't work.

i tried to add

```
document.getElementById("Reload").style.display = "block";
```

```
$("#customCheck1").on("change", function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $('#lblauto').text("Auto Reload ON")
    document.getElementById("Reload").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    $('#lblauto').text("Auto Reload OFF")
  }
})
```

(jquery)

please help

Comment: Please create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. There's nothing here that will prevent the checkbox from unchecking. Also, what does Bootstrap-4 have to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Should be working fine, you don't need the `document.getElementById("Reload").style.display = "block";` line.

```js
$("#customCheck1").on("change", function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $('#lblauto').text("Auto Reload ON")
  } else {
    $('#lblauto').text("Auto Reload OFF")
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="customCheck1" type="checkbox">
<label for="customCheck1" id="lblauto">Auto Reload OFF</label>
```

Working pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pBZYEa

Comment: the problem is, i need it

Comment: @DiaskyVB Why do you need it? Is the element hidden before you check the box?

Comment: @DiaskyVB Add your HTML and CSS to the question.